Jenkins Organization Folder for private repositories
I'm trying to setup an Organization Folder job in Jenkins with GitHub SCM and all of my organizations projects are stored in private repositories. I have tried to follow a tutorial on how to setup up one of those folders but in tutorial it uses public repositories and Jenkins doesn't see private ones when scanning. Nevertheless, theres is an option to exlude public/private repos from detection in job configuration which implies that it is capable of working with them.
After all I have:

Created a job
Created and installed GitHub App
Connected it to Jenkins

when scanning it only detects public repositories eventhough I installed the app only on selected private repositories. Is Jenkins even capable of managing GitHub Organization Folder with private repositories. I'm aware that Jenkins can work with private repos through Token or SSH but it only works with single repositories.

I checked the logs for Jenkins and found this:
WARNING        o.j.p.g.GitHubOrgWebHook#register: Failed to register GitHub Org hook to https://github.com/<my_github_username> (missing permissions?): https://api.github.com/orgs/<my_github_username> {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/orgs/orgs#get-an-organization","status":"404"}

which means that private repositories were not found because the user (me) was not registered as an organization within GitHub.
After I created a new organization and repeated the steps for it instead of my accound it worked.
